# Spring Boot - Failed to initialize ServletRegistrationBean in WebLogic 12c

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, servlet-3.0

We're running GraphQL sample Java application in WebLogic 12c, but encountered some errors with servlet during startup.

The servlet was configured and register our servlets using a ServletRegistrationBean as below:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
@ConditionalOnClass(DispatcherServlet.class)
@ConditionalOnBean({GraphQLSchema.class, GraphQLSchemaProvider.class})
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "graphql.servlet.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
@AutoConfigureAfter({GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class, SpringGraphQLCommonAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties(GraphQLServletProperties.class)

public class GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration {
    ...
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public GraphQLServlet graphQLServlet(GraphQLSchemaProvider schemaProvider, ExecutionStrategyProvider executionStrategyProvider) {
        return new SimpleGraphQLServlet(schemaProvider, executionStrategyProvider, listeners, instrumentation, errorHandler, contextBuilder);
    }

    @Bean
    ServletRegistrationBean graphQLServletRegistrationBean(GraphQLServlet servlet) {
        ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, graphQLServletProperties.getServletMapping());
        bean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

In the weblogic server log, it prints out errors:

```
<Oct 2, 2017 1:51:28 PM SGT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101125> <[ServletContext@933807824[app:CPRES module:CPRES path:null spec-version:3.1]] Error occurred while instantiating servlet: "simpleGraphQLServlet".
java.lang.InstantiationException: graphql.servlet.SimpleGraphQLServlet
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebComponentContributor.getNewInstance(WebComponentContributor.java:252)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebComponentContributor.getNewInstance(WebComponentContributor.java:245)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebComponentContributor.createServletInstance(WebComponentContributor.java:274)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.newServletInstanceIfNecessary(StubSecurityHelper.java:365)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: graphql.servlet.SimpleGraphQLServlet.<init>()
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebComponentContributor.getNewInstance(WebComponentContributor.java:252)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebComponentContributor.getNewInstance(WebComponentContributor.java:245)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebComponentContributor.createServletInstance(WebComponentContributor.java:274)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 2, 2017 1:51:28 PM SGT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101216> <Servlet: "simpleGraphQLServlet" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "CPRES".
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet class: 'graphql.servlet.SimpleGraphQLServlet' couldn't be instantiated
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:326)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:294)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:196)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Oct 2, 2017 1:51:29 PM SGT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "19094957742917053" for task "130" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet class: 'graphql.servlet.SimpleGraphQLServlet' couldn't be instantiated"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet class: 'graphql.servlet.SimpleGraphQLServlet' couldn't be instantiated
```

It looks that the weblogic is trying to create a new servlet instance instead of the ServletBean SimpleGraphQLServlet created and managed by Spring context.

Any advance? Thanks.

Comment: do you have a weblogic.xml? There you can set `prefer-application-packages`

Comment: Is your `SimpleGraphQLServlet` annotated with `@WebServlet`? If so remove it.

Comment: yes, weblogic.xml was added to the WEB-INF folder. SimpleGraphServlet is  not annotated with @WebServlet. 

When we use ServletRegistrationBean method to register a servlet in Spring Boot, will it be able to reference another bean? It gives a feeling that it only registers the servlet using bean name and then creates a new instance by servlet container.

Comment: WebLogic thinks for some reason it needs to create an instance of the servlet. So it detects it either by it being in `web.xml` a `web-fragment.xml` or being somehow registered otherwise (a custom `ServletContextInitializer` for instance or other `WebApplicationInitializer`).

Answer (score 0):

A walkaround solution is to write a Servlet wrapper class like this:

```
public class DelegateGraphQLServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected GraphQLServlet graphQLServlet;

    public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {
        super.init(servletConfig);

        ApplicationContext ac = (ApplicationContext) servletConfig.getServletContext().getAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE);
        this.graphQLServlet = (GraphQLServlet)ac.getBean("graphQLServlet");
    }

     public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
         graphQLServlet.service(req, res);
     }

}
```